# How do I know what is available in minSdkVersion in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have the following android `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mg.demo2"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Writing code in Android Studio how do I know what is available in the minSdkVersion?

When I use code completion I see:

[image]

It says Android 22 which is my targetSdkVersion not the minimal sdk version.

How do I know what is available in the `minSdkVersion`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry about that. What APIs are available is handled by the build system. You can see a list of APIs in the file `$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools/api/api-versions.xml`.

The available version and deprecated version (if it has) are clear in this XML file.

```
<class name="android/app/backup/BackupAgentHelper" since="8">
    <extends name="android/app/backup/BackupAgent" />
    <method name="&lt;init>()V" />
    <method name="addHelper(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/app/backup/BackupHelper;)V" />
</class>
```

Comment: Is there a way to see whats available in the code completion?

Comment: Yes but how can I see without from content assist which apis will work?